# Meteor: return an array element as template data

Tags: arrays, templates, meteor

Typically in Meteor templates, if you supply data through a router like iron-router, you are returning a set of documents (really a cursor) that you iterate through with the #each operator.  But what if you only want to return a specific element from some field that is an array?  I've tried several things, including the $slice operator in my query, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Are you asking something like this: "I want to pass an array from iron-router as `data` and show element n"? Or are you asking something about loading data from the DB and showing only a single field? I can't really tell without code or more explanation.

Comment: Yes, I want to pass an array from iron-router and show element n.  It's actually a sub-document: 'key: uniqueIdentifier, {myData: [ {field1: field1Value1, field2: field2Value1}, {field1: field1Value2, field2: field2Value2} ]'  ... and say I want to return the second element of myData.  Or I could return the whole document, if I just knew how to drill down to the desired array element in the template.

Comment: Okay see if the example I gave in my answer helps. You probably need something like: `return this['myData'][1];`

Comment: One trick that may help: just add a `console.log(this)` to the first line of your helper. That's a quick way to see the structure you need to access.

Comment: Well, that was a good idea I hadn't thought of.  But it showed me the structure I expected to see -- still can't figure out how to access that array element.  Here's the more detailed version:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272377/meteor-use-an-array-element-from-a-sub-document-in-template)

Comment: I finally figured out how to do it, [click here for the solution I came up with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272377/meteor-use-an-array-element-from-a-sub-document-in-template).  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple route that sets `data` to an array:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    template: 'home',
    data: [{fruit: 'apples', count: 10}, {fruit: 'oranges', count: 5}]
  });
});
```

The `home` template looks like this:

```
<template name="home">
  <p>{{snack.fruit}}: {{snack.count}}</p>
</template>
```

To show 'apples' as the snack, you need only access the first element of `this`:

```
Template.home.helpers({
  snack: function() {
    return this[0];
  }
});
```

Note, however, that `this` inside of the helpers is not actually an array - it will be an object with the same key-value pairs as the data you supplied (as well as a `yield` function apparently).

Comment: Great.  That would have taken me some time to figure out.  I should be able to make this work.  Just out of curiosity, is it possible pass a parameter to that template helper in a case like this?  Would {{snack.fruit parameter}} work?

Comment: No you can't pass parameters to your template helpers. You can pass parameters to a [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) helper, e.g. `{{formatSnackCount snack.count}}` where `formatSnackCount` has been registered with `Handlebars.registerHelper`.

Comment: Thanks for this! Another nugget of clarity while learning the basics of Meteor :)