# Meteor: Use an array element from a sub-document in template

Tags: templates, meteor

I have a Mongo document like this:

```
{
    stKey: "apples001",
    i: [        
        {q: "What are apples?", a1: "Apples are fruits.", a2: "Fruit."},
        {q: "How do apples taste?", a1: "Apples taste sweet.", a2: "Sweet."} 
    ]
}
```

... and I want to be able to use the contents of i: above in my template.  For my route, I have this:

```
  this.route('teacherCue', { 
  path: '/',
  data: function() {
      templateData = { interactionSet: PL.find( 
          {stKey: 'apples001'}
      )};
      return templateData;
  }
});
```

My template looks like this:

```
<template name="teacherCue">

    {{#each interactionSet}}

      <a href="#">{{interaction.q}}</a>
        <ul>        
            <p><a href="#">{{interaction.a1}}</a> </p> 
            <p><a href="#">{{interaction.a2}}</a> </p>   
        </ul>

    {{/each}}

</template>
```

So the question is: how do I create a template helper (or a Handlebars helper) so that 'interaction' in {{interaction.q}}, etc. references a specific array element from the field 'i'? Or is there another way to achieve this same result? At this point, I don't care if I can pass a parameter to the helper to get it or not.  The index into the array can be gotten from a session variable, if I have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this one took a lot of tinkering to solve, and there may well be a simpler way, but here is a method that works to return specific array elements from a sub-document as template data.  Originally, I was trying to use an #each to establish the data context for the template, but that was just confusing things, b/c I don't want to iterate through a result set, I want to use a single document for my data. Specifically I want to use an object that is an element in an object array in that document; and assign different values from that object to template values, like {{myValue1}}.

So what I had to to do was turn my object array field into a "real array" using jQuery (which gave me an array of objects) and then access the right element in that array and turn **it** into an array!  Finally, to access the individual value pairs in the desired object, I had to use a syntax like myArray[0].fieldName.

```
this.route('teacherCue', {

  path: '/',

  data: function() {

      desiredIndex = 0;

      var record = PL.findOne( {stKey: 'apples001'} );

      var objArray = $.makeArray( record.i );

      iArray = $.makeArray( objArray[desiredIndex] );

      return {q: iArray[0].q, a1: iArray[0].a1, a2: iArray[0].a2, q2: iArray[0].q2}
  }
});
```

Thanks to Sean for pointing me in the right direction with his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need another helper to access the data that's already defined, simply use it with `this` keyword:

```
{{#each interactionSet}}
  <a href="#">{{this.q}}</a>   
    <ul>        
        <p><a href="#">{{this.a1}}</a> </p> 
        <p><a href="#">{{this.a2}}</a> </p>   
    </ul>
{{/each}}
```

---

You also have a bug in the code. `templateData` should be defined with `var` keyword, otherwise you're writing to a global variable - which will lead to conflicts sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks for the info about var.  I thought that undeclared variables inside of functions were local.  That was going to cause a huge mystifying mess if I had continued along that road!

Answer (score 1):

The array resides in the `i` property of your mongo record, so you would want to return just that in the `interactionSet` template variable instead of the whole record. Also, you would want to use `findOne` instead of `find`, since you're looking for a specific record. Modify your code like so:

```
this.route('teacherCue', { 
  path: '/',
  data: function() {
    var record = PL.findOne({stKey: 'apples001'});
    var templateData = { interactionSet: record.i };
    return templateData;
  }
});
```

Also, you do not need the `interaction.` prefix when writing out data in the body of your template's `each` loop. Your template should look something like this instead:

```
<template name="teacherCue">

    {{#each interactionSet}}

        <a href="#">{{q}}</a>
        <ul>        
            <p><a href="#">{{a1}}</a> </p> 
            <p><a href="#">{{a2}}</a> </p>   
        </ul>

    {{/each}}

</template>
```

Comment: This gives the error: "Exception from Deps recompute: Error: {{#each}} only accepts arrays, cursors, or falsey values. You passed: [object Object]"  But this idea is giving me some new ideas.  So I'm still trying!  The big problem is trying to get a specific element out of the i field, which is an array of objects.

Comment: Perhaps your data structure is different than what you posted in your question? I tried my solution out, and everything seemed to work fine. You can try adding a `console.log(templateData);` line to the `data` function of your route to see what's actually in there.

Comment: Here are the contents of the two files I created to test this out, [app.js](http://pastebin.com/YaqSg0qE) and [templates.html](http://pastebin.com/86n3CnUh).

Comment: Interesting.  My data structure is exactly the same as what's in your file.  I encounter this error whenever I pass (as data) a single record to a template that uses #each on that data.  I'm curious, did you try to access the second element of the i field?  Before I posted my question, I came up with several solutions that worked to display the first (the zeroth) element of the array, but I  couldn't get beyond that.  And, yeah, that trick of logging an object to the console is super-handy.  I had do it repeatedly to make my solution work.

Comment: The `{{#each interactionSet}}` loop in my template displayed both elements of the `i` array with no problems ([screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/ZQ8quci.png)).

Comment: OK, I tried your code again and I didn't get the error this time!  I don't know what I did wrong before.  And if you read my solution below, you'll see I posted code originally that was misleading, as far as what I was trying to achieve is concerned.  But it was your method of narrowing down the data to be returned that helped me figure out my solution.  Thanks again.